# Adding data into html table

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add data in the format given below into html table using only jQuery. I haven't used jQuery much before. Can anyone help me with it.

**Data:**

```
var data = [
    addStudentData("Isaac Netwon", "isanew1", "secret", "1", "en"),
    addStudentData("Thales", "thales1", "secret", "1", "en"),
    addStudentData("Pythagoras", "pythag1", "secret", "1", "es"),
    addStudentData("Albert Einstein", "albein1", "secret", "1", "es"),
    addStudentData("Euclid", "euclid1", "secret", "1", "es"),
    addStudentData("Blaise Pascal", "blapas1", "secret", "1", "es"),
    addStudentData("Alan Turing", "alatur1", "secret", "1", "es"),
    addStudentData("Ada Lovelace", "adalov1", "secret", "1", "en"),
    addStudentData("Blaise Pascal", "blapas1", "secret", "1", "es"),
    addStudentData("Benjamin Banneker", "benban1", "secret", "1", "en"),
    addStudentData("John von Neumann", "johneu1", "secret", "1", "es") ]
```

**Function:**

```
function addStudentData(name, user, pass, gen, lan) {
return {"name":name, "username":user, "password":pass, "gender":gen, "language":lan}; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can jQuery append() function to append an opening tag for a row, then the opening tag for the cell, information, then ending tags like this.

`var obj = {name:"bill", username:"billy", password:"pass", gender:"gen", language:"lan"};
        var obj2 = {name:"bob", username:"bobby", password:"pass2", gender:"gen2", language:"lan2"};
        var data = [];
        data.push(obj);
        data.push(obj2);
        populate(data);`

```
    function populate(array){
        $("#table").append("<tr><td>" + array[1].name + "</td><td>" + array[1].username + "</td></tr>");
    }`
```

using a for loop to go through as many elements as you have in your array

Comment: should i not use addStudentData function?

Comment: look at spazmoe06 answer. use your function to populate your data array and then use append to create the table, rows, and cells.

Answer (score 0):

Using the function you already created create a new function and use JQuery's `.append()` and `.each()`.

```
function addStudentData(name, user, pass, gen, lan) {
  return {"name":name, "username":user, "password":pass, "gnder":gen, "language":lan};
}
function  build() {
    var data = [ 
            addStudentData("Isaac Netwon", "isanew1", "secret", "1", "en"), 
            addStudentData("Thales", "thales1", "secret", "1", "en"),
            addStudentData("Pythagoras", "pythag1", "secret", "1", "es"), 
            addStudentData("Albert Einstein", "albein1", "secret", "1", "es"), 
            addStudentData("Euclid", "euclid1", "secret", "1", "es"), 
            addStudentData("Blaise Pascal", "blapas1", "secret", "1", "es"), 
            addStudentData("Alan Turing", "alatur1", "secret", "1", "es"), 
            addStudentData("Ada Lovelace", "adalov1", "secret", "1", "en"),
            addStudentData("Blaise Pascal", "blapas1", "secret", "1", "es"), 
            addStudentData("Benjamin Banneker", "benban1", "secret", "1", "en"), 
            addStudentData("John von Neumann", "johneu1", "secret", "1", "es")
        ],
        $parentTag = $(".yourParentTag"), //replace with your own selector
        $table = $(document.createElement("table")),
        $thead = $(document.createElement("thead")),
        $tbody = $(document.createElement("tbody")),
        $headRow = $(document.createElement("tr"));

    // Append table elements together.
    $table.append($thead);
    $table.append($tbody);
    $thead.append($headRow);
    $parentTag.append($table);
    $thead.find("tr").addClass("headerRow");


    // Creates the the table header from the object key
    $.each(data[0], function (i, v) {
        var $th = $(document.createElement("th")).text(i);
        $(".headerRow").append($th);
    });

    // Outter each creates the rows for the body
    $.each(data, function () {
        var $row = $(document.createElement("tr"));

        //Inner each creates the cells in the table
        $.each(this, function (i, v) {
            $td = $(document.createElement("td")).text(v);
            $row.append($td);
        });
        // Appends the row to the table body.
        $tbody.append($row);
    });
}
// Call the build function. 
build();
```

Not really sure what this looking like in the end but you could also make the build function self invoking.

Comment: This gives me clear direction thanks. I am thinking of creating a table and headers using html and just append the data in it using jQuery. Does that seem to be correct way too?

Comment: That would work just fine as well. The reason I created the headers there is because your object had keys that looked kinda like column titles. Just leave off the code that you are hand rolling and keep the parts that you need to be populated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fvaq2g51/ is what is the result. I doesnt go inside the data variable and reads it.

Comment: It appears you forgot to append the $tbody to $parentTag. Just do $parentTag.append ($tbody); near where you append $thead to the table.